# Google Apps Script - Unique values results are not Unique

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, unique

I am fairly new to Google Apps Script, but I am working on using some scripting to summarise the data in some Google Sheets databases I am developing.  It will also help with populating a dashboard for each spreadsheet.

I have this sheet as an example:
[Austria TEST2](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/18N-y6cr6Cl2Ho4aaynMh4kCLcQXhjFNVXvFNUcqn-Hw/edit?usp=sharing)

To start with, I would like to take the data in column L of sheet 'Data', find the unique non-blank values and then count how many of each their are, sort the list in descending order and the write it to columns C and D of sheet 'Summary'.

Here is my code:

```
// ************  Operators
  // load non-empty values into an array
  var data = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Data").getRange("L2:L").getValues().filter(String);
  var uniqueValues = [];

  // Find the unique values in the data.
  for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
  if (!uniqueValues.includes(data[i][0])) {
  uniqueValues.push([data[i][0], 0]);
  }
  }

  // Count the occurrences of each unique value.
  for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
  for (var j = 0; j < uniqueValues.length; j++) {
  if (uniqueValues[j][0] === data[i][0]) {
  uniqueValues[j][1]++;
  }
  }
  } 
  
  // Sort the array according to column 2.
  uniqueValues.sort(function(a, b) {
  return b[1] - a[1];
  });

  // Insert header row - both ways give errors!!
  //uniqueValues2[2][uniqueValues.length+1] = uniqueValues;
  //var length = uniqueValues.unshift('Operator','Qty');

  // 1st row, 1st col, no of rows, no of cols
  SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Summary").getRange(2,3,uniqueValues.length,2).setValues(uniqueValues);
```

Here is my column L data:

```
Anisec Luftfahrt Gmbh
Austrian Airlines
Baltic Jet Aircompany
Easyjet
Easyjet
Easyjet
Easyjet
Easyjet
Easyjet
Easyjet
Easyjet
Easyjet
Easyjet Europe
Easyjet Europe
Easyjet Europe
Easyjet Europe
Flymed
Laudamotion Gmbh
Mhs Aviation Gmbh
Tnt Airways
Trytofly
```

I would expect to get:

```
Easyjet 9
Easyjet Europe 4
Anisec Luftfahrt Gmbh 1
Austrian Airlines 1
Baltic Jet Aircompany 1
Flymed 1
Laudamotion Gmbh 1
Mhs Aviation Gmbh 1
Tnt Airways 1
Trytofly 1
```

but I actually get:

```
Easyjet 9
Easyjet 9
Easyjet 9
Easyjet 9
Easyjet 9
Easyjet 9
Easyjet 9
Easyjet 9
Easyjet 9
Easyjet Europe  4
Easyjet Europe  4
Easyjet Europe  4
Easyjet Europe  4
Anisec Luftfahrt Gmbh   1
Austrian Airlines   1
Baltic Jet Aircompany   1
Flymed  1
Laudamotion Gmbh    1
Mhs Aviation Gmbh   1
Tnt Airways 1
Trytofly    1
```

As far as I can see the code logic is correct, it should load new values into 'uniqueValues' from 'data' if they don't already exist, and ignore them if they do exist.  But that's not what the output shows, the code seems to be defying its own logic!

If I can get this bit work I will later turn it into a generic function with passed parameters, to use on the other columns of the database.  Thanks for any help in this.

Comment: `const u =[...new Set(data.flat())]`

Comment: No, that gives:

A 2
A 2
E 2
E 2
T 2
T 2
B 1
F 1
L 1
M 1

Comment: What's the output of `console.log(JSON.stringify(data))`?

Comment: The output is this:
[["Anisec Luftfahrt Gmbh"],["Austrian Airlines"],["Baltic Jet Aircompany"],["Easyjet"],["Easyjet"],["Easyjet"],["Easyjet"],["Easyjet"],["Easyjet"],["Easyjet"],["Easyjet"],["Easyjet"],["Easyjet Europe"],["Easyjet Europe"],["Easyjet Europe"],["Easyjet Europe"],["Flymed"],["Laudamotion Gmbh"],["Mhs Aviation Gmbh"],["Tnt Airways"],["Trytofly"]]

Comment: What's the output of `const u =[...new Set(data.flat())];console.log(u)`?

Answer (score 0):

**Unique Sorted posted into sheet with null column next two it**

```
function myfunk() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet3");
  const osh = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet4");
  const data = sh.getRange("L2:L" + sh.getLastRow()).getValues().flat();
  let uA = [...new Set(data)].sort((a,b) => {return b - a}).filter(e => e).map(e => [e,'']);
  osh.getRange(2,3,uA.length,uA[0].length).setValues(uA);
}
```

- [google-apps-script reference](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference)
- [javascript reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript)
- [Learn More](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/google-apps-script/info)

Comment: That at least finds the unique values, but leaves the count column empty:
Anisec Luftfahrt Gmbh
Austrian Airlines
Baltic Jet Aircompany
Easyjet
Easyjet Europe
Flymed
Laudamotion Gmbh
Mhs Aviation Gmbh
Tnt Airways
Trytofly

A bit of that with the second half of my existing code might work.

Comment: Interestingly, for the Cooper code above, the console output is this:
["Anisec Luftfahrt Gmbh","Austrian Airlines","Baltic Jet Aircompany","Easyjet","Easyjet","Easyjet","Easyjet","Easyjet","Easyjet","Easyjet","Easyjet","Easyjet","Easyjet Europe","Easyjet Europe","Easyjet Europe","Easyjet Europe","Flymed","Laudamotion Gmbh","Mhs Aviation Gmbh","Tnt Airways","Trytofly"]

with only one set of brackets.

Answer (score 0):

Use [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) to get counts:

```js
/*<ignore>*/console.config({maximize:true,timeStamps:false,autoScroll:false});/*</ignore>*/ 
const data = [
  ['Anisec Luftfahrt Gmbh'],
  ['Austrian Airlines'],
  ['Baltic Jet Aircompany'],
  ['Easyjet'],
  ['Easyjet'],
  ['Easyjet'],
  ['Easyjet'],
  ['Easyjet'],
  ['Easyjet'],
  ['Easyjet'],
  ['Easyjet'],
  ['Easyjet'],
  ['Easyjet Europe'],
  ['Easyjet Europe'],
  ['Easyjet Europe'],
  ['Easyjet Europe'],
  ['Flymed'],
  ['Laudamotion Gmbh'],
  ['Mhs Aviation Gmbh'],
  ['Tnt Airways'],
  ['Trytofly'],
];

const o = Object.entries(
  data.reduce(
    (o, [val]) => ((o[val] = (o[val] ?? 0) + 1), o),
    Object.create(null)
  )
);
console.log(o);
```

```html
<!-- https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/375985/ -->    <script src="https://gh-canon.github.io/stack-snippet-console/console.min.js"></script>
```

Then `setValues` the `o`  array.

---

Your code fails here

```
uniqueValues.includes(data[i][0])
```

because `uniqueValues` is a 2D array. You can try `findIndex` instead:

```
if(uniqueValues.findIndex(e => e[0] === data[i][0])<0)
```